# APNS Java simple implementation with SOCKS support (Apple Push Notification Service)

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, socks

I have been looking for an easy to integrate, simple and lightweight Java implementation of APNS (Apple Push Notification Service).

2 java libraries are (equally?) popular :

- javapns
- java-apns.

Both are quite bloated and complex to integrate, although they (as usually) claim it's very simple. Both libraries claim SOCKS proxy support, but I did not manage to get it working, and after hours digging the source code and doing many tries I'm looking for another solution.

Anyone has a Java simple implementation of that ? I think it should be possible to deliver the functionnality in only one class.
Please note I need SOCKS proxy support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote my own single class implementation for sending notification through APNS.

Below is the code, hoping it helps. 
Note that the payload formatting (title, text, sound, etc.) of the notification is not here, nor is the queueing for sending to a lot of smartphones.
This implementation works with or without SOCKS proxies, see the code for details.

```
public class APNSHelper
{
private static SSLContext sslContext;
private static SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
private static SSLSocket sslSocket; 
private static DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "sunx509";
private final static byte COMMAND = 0;

private static long lastSucessfulSocketUsageMillis = 0L;

private static void initSSL() throws Exception
{
    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.initSSL() begin");
    try
    {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(Constants.IOS_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
        final KeyStore lks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);
        lks.load(stream, Constants.IOS_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        final KeyManagerFactory lkmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        lkmf.init(lks, Constants.IOS_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        final TrustManagerFactory ltmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        ltmf.init((KeyStore)null);
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(lkmf.getKeyManagers(), ltmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.error("ApnsHelper.initSSL: " + e);
        throw e;
    }
    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.initSSL() end");
}

private static Socket getSocket() throws Exception
{
    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket() begin");

    if (sslSocketFactory == null) initSSL();

    if (sslSocket != null)
    {
        try
        {
            dataOutputStream.close();
            sslSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.error("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): closing sslSocket: " + e);
        }
        dataOutputStream = null;
        sslSocket = null;
    }

    try
    {
        Socket infraSocket = null;
        if (Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST != null && Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST.length() > 0)
        {
            Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): with SOCKS PROXY=" + Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST + ":" + Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_PORT);

            InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST, Constants.IOS_PUSH_SOCKS_PROXY_PORT);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);
            infraSocket = new Socket(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): NO proxy");

            // NO SOCKS version
            infraSocket = new Socket();
        }

        InetSocketAddress targetAddr = new InetSocketAddress(Constants.IOS_PUSH_GATEWAY_HOST, Constants.IOS_PUSH_GATEWAY_PORT);
        infraSocket.connect(targetAddr);
        sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(infraSocket, Constants.IOS_PUSH_GATEWAY_HOST, Constants.IOS_PUSH_GATEWAY_PORT, true);

        Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): starting SSL handshake");
        sslSocket.startHandshake();
        Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): ended SSL handshake");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logger.error("ApnsHelper.getSocket(): " + e);
        throw e;
    }

    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.getSocket() end");

    return sslSocket;
}

private static int hexValue(final char c) throws Exception
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return (c - '0');
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return (c - 'a') + 10;
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return (c - 'A') + 10;

    Logger.error("Invalid hex char='" + c + "'");
    throw new Exception("Invalid hex char='" + c + "'");
}

public static synchronized void apnsPush(String mobileUIDID, String payLoad)
{
    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.apnsPush(mobileUIDID=" + mobileUIDID + ", payLoad=" + payLoad+ ") begin");

    int ltries = 0;
    while( ltries < 3)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sslSocket == null || lastSucessfulSocketUsageMillis + Constants.IOS_PUSH_STALLED_MAX_TIME < System.currentTimeMillis())
            {
                getSocket();
            }
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream()));

            byte[] lpayLoad = payLoad.getBytes("UTF-8");
            final byte[] deviceId = new byte[mobileUIDID.length() / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < deviceId.length; i++) deviceId[i] = (byte) ((hexValue(mobileUIDID.charAt(2*i)) * 16 + hexValue(mobileUIDID.charAt(2*i + 1))));

            dataOutputStream.writeByte(COMMAND);
            dataOutputStream.writeShort(deviceId.length);
            dataOutputStream.write(deviceId);
            dataOutputStream.writeShort(lpayLoad.length);
            dataOutputStream.write(lpayLoad);

            dataOutputStream.flush();
            lastSucessfulSocketUsageMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.apnsPush(): sent message, mobileUIDID=" + mobileUIDID + ", payLoad=" + payLoad);
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.error("ApnsHelper.apnsPush(): " + e);
            ltries++;
        }
    }
    Logger.debug("ApnsHelper.apnsPush(mobileUIDID=" + mobileUIDID + ", payLoad=" + payLoad+ ") end");
}
```

}
}'